# Understand definition of First Order Frame Field

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, field-theory, lie-groups, riemannian-geometry

Could anyone help me understand what these stars are and who are the omega?
I suspect there is pullback, but I'm not sure.[image]

Where $\mathbf{x}%
:M\rightarrow 
%TCIMACRO{\U{211d} }%
%BeginExpansion
N
%EndExpansion
$ is the imersion.